# Add new fields in the product page admin Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop-1.7

I managed to add new fields in the frontend and in the ps_product table so that we can save our values in the database, so far it's working. Now I would like to add these new fields in the admin frontend, in the product page in order to be able to modify the values of the ps_product table as admin. Would you know what files to modify?
Prestashop 1.7

mon nouveau champ fonctionnel (hors admin):

modules\kbmarketplace\views\templates\front\product\shipping.tpl

```
                <li class="kb-form-l">
                    <div class="kb-form-label-block">
                        <span class="kblabel ">{l s='field_cuisto1' mod='kbmarketplace'}
                    </div>
                    <div class="kb-form-field-block">
                        <div class="kb-labeled-inpfield">
                         <!--<span class="inplbl">{$field_cuisto1|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</span>-->
                         <input type="text" class="kb-inpfield" validate="isGenericName" name="field_cuisto1" value="{$field_cuisto1|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" maxlength="255"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </li>
```

classes\Product.php    dans public static $definition (array)

```
'field_cuisto1' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 255],
'field_cuisto_horaire' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 255],
'field_cuisto_max_hour' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 255],
'field_cuisto_jours' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 255],
```

modules\kbmarketplace\controllers\front\kbproduct.php

```
public function initFormShipping()
    {
    $properties = array('width', 'height', 'depth', 'weight', 'additional_shipping_cost', 'field_cuisto1', 'field_cuisto_max_hour', 'field_cuisto_horaire', 'field_cuisto_jours'); 

[...]

$_POST['field_cuisto1'] = (!Tools::getIsset('field_cuisto1')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('field_cuisto1'));
$_POST['field_cuisto_jours'] = (!Tools::getIsset('field_cuisto_jours')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('field_cuisto_jours'));
$_POST['field_cuisto_max_hour'] = (!Tools::getIsset('field_cuisto_max_hour')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('field_cuisto_max_hour'));
$_POST['field_cuisto_horaire'] = (!Tools::getIsset('field_cuisto_horaire')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('field_cuisto_horaire'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use hooks to do that:

```
  public function hookDisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle($params) {
        $product = new Product($params['id_product']);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'your_custom_field' => $product->your_custom_field,
            'your_custom_field_lang' => $product->your_custom_field_lang
            )
           );

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/shipping.tpl');
    }
```

here is an exemple you can find list of hooks [here](https://www.team-ever.com/prestashop-1-7-la-liste-des-hooks/)